# How can I make sure that the iPhone simulator in Xcode will move past the the startup screen every time I use it?

Tags: ios, xcode

When I run the iPhone simulator, sometimes it doesn't move past the opening screen, and sometimes it does.

What I am calling the opening screen is the screen which has the app tittle on it.

I have tried closing and re-opening it. But it doesn't seem to solve the problem, as it still comes back.

I am using the new Xcode beta but this problem also happens to me often in Xcode 6.

Answer (score 2):

This happens to me too sometimes. Simply stop and directly press the "Run" button again.

You can also try to change the Device or uninstall your app on the selected device.

Also try to close the Simulator and open it again and try to run your app after that

Answer (score 2):

The simulator in my opinion is a little buggy to me.  This seems to happen to me a lot the first time I run the simulator.  After that it seems a little more stable.

Comment: In Xcode I can see that the simulator says it is "paused." This happens overtime I try to launch.

Answer (score 0):

My answer is you cannot make **sure** about that, since it is just a simulator.

This happen to me to when i use xcode6 sometimes, but when i use xcode 5.1.1 it is working perfectly.

I think xcode6 do not stop the current running app before running the other instead it just override the current "same" running app. here is my theory as i observe it.

Assuming simulator is running.

in XCode 5.1.1:

***Stops the currently running app*** > ***Compile*** > ***Run***

but in XCode 6:

***Compile*** > ***Override the same running app***

But you dont want to worry about that so much, as long as it doesn't appear in actual device it is all good.